# ng-template with ui.router, separate files

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

At the moment I'm using `ng-template` in my index.html file like this today,

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.html">
  //html here...
</script>
```

I'm also using ui.router, and that looks like this,

```
             $stateProvider
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/home',
                    templateUrl: '/home.html',
                    controller: 'mainController',
                    resolve: {
                        postPromise: ['serv', function(serv) {
                            return serv.getAll();
                        }]
                    }
                });
```

This works fine. 
The thing is I want to scale my application and learn more about best practice and how to actually work with angular. My background is .NET MVC where there is master / view / partial view. So I'm trying to do the sameish approach here with angular, but in my case I have the `index.html` as master, and `home.html` would be view or partial if you will. Appriciate all input I get.

Comment: Probably better if you split your `views` into different `.tpl.html` files and `templateUrl: 'path/to/view.tpl.html'`

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a same-ish approach here - at least with angular 1.x (haven't yet delved into 2). :)

Two nice sources I've come across back when I was looking into this are:

1. [John Papa Angular style guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)
2. [Best practices on structuring Angular app](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure)

Together they should point in the right direction.

Answer (score -1):

You might consider using `<ng-view>` in your index.html file.

index.html

```
<body>

        <ng-include src="'app/views/structure/navigation.tpl.html'"></ng-include>

        <ng-view autoscroll="true"></ng-view>

        <ng-include src="'app/views/structure/footer.tpl.html'"></ng-include >

        <!--Scripts-->
        <!--<script src="bower_components/masonry/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>-->
        <!--<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
        <script src="assets/libs/flexslider/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/masonry/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/imagesloaded/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

In your module you can make it look like:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']);
```

The above is naturally a different file.

Now you can have your `app.routes` file:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/',{
        templateUrl: "app/views/misc/home.tpl.html",
        controller: "HomeController"
    })
    .when('/about',{
        templateUrl: "app/views/misc/about.tpl.html",
        controller: "AboutController"
    })
   .when('/hobbies',{
         templateUrl: "app/views/pages/hobbies.html",
         controller: "HobbiesController"
   }).otherwise({redirectTo:'/'});

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Now you need a controller:

```
    app.controller('HomeController', function($scope, ROOT) {
    $scope.Root = ROOT;
    console.log("In Home Controller")
    $scope.top = {

        backstretch: [
            ROOT+'/assets/img/big/big-1.jpg',
            ROOT+'/assets/img/big/big-2.jpg',
            ROOT+'/assets/img/big/big-4.jpg'
        ]
    };
});
```

Now since I used `HomeController` I will use that for this example.

My routes file said `when('/')` go to the file path `app/views/misc/home.tpl.html` and the controller is `HomeController`. Since in my `app.module` file I used `var app = angular.module` I can just write `app.controller('HomeController)`, now everything is hooked up.

In my `home.tpl.html` all I have to do is put `<div>` tags.

Depending on the size of the project will depict the design. The larger the project the more modular you want to make it.

Comment: not really what I'm looking for, I'm working with `ui.route`